# Facebook Integration iOS SDK (Facebook Connect)?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, facebook

I am trying to use Facebook Connect to connect to Facebook but all the tutorials I find (including in a book) are not legible. They cause errors and some files don't exist, I am assuming they are fully outdated. I cannot find ANY working tutorials up to date. Do you know any? I am using the Facebook iOS SDK FBConnect downloaded from github. If not can you provide me with step to step details? I just want to post a certain string (some text irrelevant to the topic) onto their wall. I have implemented Twitter and mail but not Facebook. I am also aware of ShareKit but do not know how to use it, is there any clear tutorials for that?

I have created an app on the Facebook developers site so I have all the details (API key and secret key) in place. Thank you.
Regards,
Rohan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tutorial:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/ios/build/

Sample:

https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/tree/master/sample/Hackbook

//run app
[image]

Comment: I suggest, download the hackbook app code to see sdk in action. and see the implementations

Comment: accept (check button) is under the down button if you think my answer is correct :) and your welcome.

Comment: i can't run the project. i can only build it. does this have no simulation involved?

Comment: you can run it on simulator. how do you run it btw? check your scheme

Comment: wait i don't get those options for me

Comment: wait how do i actually download the actual Hackbook project i just download the Facebook connect api